# Initializing a vector class member in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initializer

I'm trying to set length and initialize a `vector` member of a class, but it seems it's only possible if initializing line is out of class.

```
//a vector, out of class set size to 5. initialized each value to Zero
vector<double> vec(5,0.0f);//its ok

class Bird{

public:
    int id;
    //attempt to init is not possible if a vector a class of member
    vector<double> vec_(5, 0.0f);//error: expected a type specifier
}
```

How can I do this inside the class?

Comment: in C++11, you can have default member values, but not in C++98. The syntax is `vector<double> vec_ = vector<double>(5, 0.0f);`

Answer (score 13):

Use the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
class Bird{

public:
    int id;
    vector<double> vec_;

    Bird(int pId):id(pId), vec_(5, 0.0f)
    {
    }
}
```

This is also useful for initializing base classes that lack a default constructor and anything else you'd rather have constructed before the body of the constructor executes.

Answer (score 8):

As Franck mentioned, the modern c++ way of initializing class member vector is

```
vector<double> vec_ = vector<double>(5, 0.0f);//vector of size 5, each with value 0.0
```

Note that for vectors of int, float, double etc (AKA in built types) we do not need to zero initialize. So better way to do this is

```
vector<double> vec_ = vector<double>(5);//vector of size 5, each with value 0.0
```